# Can't kill Spark app with SparkLauncher and SparkAppHandle

Tags: apache-spark, spark-launcher

According to [this documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html#startApplication(org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkAppHandle.Listener...)) a Spark app, which was started/submitted with the SparkLauncher and the method `startApplication`, can be killed with the returned SparkAppHandle  and the `kill()` method, as it's a child-process. I tried to implement this in combination with a CountDownLatch and a timer, but it doesn't work for me. 
The Java-app with the SparkLauncher is finishing after 20min, but the spark app is still running on my YARN-cluster afterwards.

I'm using the following code:

```
`
// launcher config...
CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
Listener handleListeners = new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(SparkAppHandle handle) {
        if (handle.getState().isFinal()) {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void infoChanged(SparkAppHandle handle) {}
    };

countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
SparkAppHandle handle = launcher.startApplication(handleListeners);
boolean regularExit = countDownLatch.await(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
if (!regularExit)
    handle.kill();
```

`
I'm still wondering that the kill-command shall work when it's already running on the cluster.

(Please, can somebody fix the code-snippet? I don't get it properly formatted -_- Thanks.)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @Mumla

Comment: Unfortunately not. I assume that this is (/was?) a bug. I also just noticed that the documentation doesn't contain the information about this kill-method anymore since version 2.3.0.